# Adding posts from my blog to chat

Tags: discussion, chat

I'm getting asked by a couple people in the Root Access chat room about posts I make on my blog. I know we have the SU blog that posts updates there, as well as GFSE. Would it be OK for me to make a feed for my blog as well on the RA chat room? For reference, the link is http://talk-about-it.ca, and it is usually containing information I found either through work, or from areas of the Stack Exchange (with attribution).

Comment: nothing preventing you from doing that, as long as majority of chat folks don't mind

Comment: I don't think anyone would mind as long as it's relevant to SU and not automated in a spammy-way.

Comment: Feeds post a message once per new blog post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No one is yelling at me for it, so I went ahead and did it

Comment: **HEY!!!!!** I've always wanted to yell at you.  Since you opened it up I thought I'd take the chance.  You may proceed without any further opposition from me.  However, I think that for every link you publish is another post you owe me/the blog ;)